# What is the name of the snake-like sand streams the wind blows on the beach?

Tags: nouns, proper-nouns

Does the phenomenon seen in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SxnW7ObqXPg&ab_channel=ViralHog) have a specific name?

Once, on a tv show, I saw someone call it "sand snakes", but I never found a second source to verify people use that designation in everyday life. It could be that the screenwriters wrote that specifically for such a show (I don't remember which it was.)

Some people on the internet call them "sand waves", but sand wave refers to [the stationary accretion of sand due to wind.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sand_wave)

Answer (score 1):

I would call them 'saltation streamers', 'aeolian streamers', or just 'streamers'. In geology, the technical term for transport of dry grains of stones, soil, sand, dust, etc, by a stream of wind or water is 'saltation', and 'aeolian' means 'relating to or arising from the action of the wind.'

[image]

[The physics of wind-blown sand and dust](http://geosci.uchicago.edu/%7Ekite/doc/Kok_et_al_2012.pdf)

[Sand dunes](http://www.geography-site.co.uk/pages/physical/coastal/dunes.html)